# Button on Backend call method PHP

Tags: magento-1.9

The button in my module:

### system.xml

```
                <update translate="label">
                    <frontend_type>button</frontend_type>
                    <frontend_model>mateusvitali_sigepweb/button</frontend_model>
                    <sort_order>300</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                </update>
```

I want to call a method (php) by clicking on the button. I created the class `MateusVitali_SigepWeb_Block_Button` too.

---

Ok, I tried to follow this tutorial: 
http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-button-to-system-configuration/

But the method is not called and the alert does not appear.

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/MateusVitali/system/config/updateButtin.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function update() {
        new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $this->getAjaxCheckUrl() ?>', {
            method:     'get',
            onSuccess: function(transport){
                if (transport.responseText){
                    alert('Updated!');
                }
            }
        });
    }
    //]]>
</script>

<?php echo $this->getButtonHtml() ?>
```

app/code/local/MateusVitali/SigepWeb/Controllers/Adminhtml/MateusVitaliSigepWebController.php

```
class MateusVitali_SigepWeb_Adminhtml_MateusVitaliSigepWebController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    /**
     * Return some checking result
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function updateAction()
    {
        $result = 1;
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setBody($result);
    }
}
```

app/code/local/MateusVitali/SigepWeb/Block/Button.php

```
class MateusVitali_SigepWeb_Block_Button extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{
    /*
     * Set template
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('mateusvitali/system/config/updateButton.phtml');
    }

    /**
     * Return element html
     *
     * @param  Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Return ajax url for button
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAjaxCheckUrl()
    {
        return Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/adminhtml_mateusvitalisigepweb/update');
    }

    /**
     * Generate button html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getButtonHtml()
    {
        $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
            ->setData(array(
            'id'        => 'update_button',
            'label'     => 'Atualizar Serviços',
            'onclick'   => 'javascript:update(); return false;'
        ));

        return $button->toHtml();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you probably don't want to reload the page, you'll need to create a custom controller and call it with AJAX. Use the prototype.js AJAX methods in your custom button: http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Request/

Comment: Ok, added information in the initial doubts